# Threading questions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

1. If I spawn a secondary thread and the threaded method calls other methods, are those methods run in the secondary thread or the main thread?
2. Is there a way to determine on which thread a specified piece of code is being run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All method calls take place in the current thread, unless you do something like `performSelectorInBackground:`
2. You can probably tell if you're running in the main thread by comparing `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` to `[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]`

See also: [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading)

Comment: (1), alternately stated: All messages to objects are received on the same thread they're sent from. Nothing creates a thread unless it explicitly creates a thread. (“Documented as creating a thread” counts as “explicitly creates a thread.”) (2): Or send `[NSThread isMainThread]`. However, the program should not need to test whether it is running on the main thread. Any given piece of code should either (a) only ever run on (the main|a secondary) thread or (b) not care what thread it's running on.